# Extracting an HTML ID using Jmeter regular expression extractor

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I have a requirement to fetch the ID of a `<tr>` tag based on the country name (`TestIndia1`). I am trying to edit the record, but while editing, it requires the ID.

So please let me know how to fetch the ID from the `html` using a regular expression.

```
<tr role="row" id="241" tabindex="-1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr">
    <td role="gridcell" style="text-align:center;width: 30px;" aria-describedby="list2_cb">
    <input role="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="jqg_list2_241" class="regular-checkbox cbox" name="jqg_list2_241"><label for="jqg_list2_241">
    </label></td><td role="gridcell" aria-describedby="list2_subgrid" class="ui-sgcollapsed sgcollapsed " style="">
    <a style="cursor:pointer;"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span></a></td>
    <td role="gridcell" style="text-align:left;" aria-describedby="list2_mc_country"><a class="inline-edit-link " href="http://example.com|id|241">TestIndia1</a></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Add [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) as a child of the request which returns that HTML
2. Configure it as follows:

   - If response is not XHTML-compliant check `Use Tidy` box
   - Reference Name: arbitrary JMeter Variable name, i.e. `ID`
   - XPath Query: `//a[text()='TestIndia1']/ancestor::*/tr/@id`
3. Refer the extracted value as `${ID}` where required.

Useful links:

- [XPath 1.0 Language Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)
- [XPath Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/)
- [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Dmitri , I need the same in regular extractor, because in response I am getting the json data. So I dont have chance to use xpath extractor

Comment: There is a [JSON Path Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) plugin which works fine with JSON data. It's described in aforementioned "Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter guide", just scroll down to "Parsing JSON" section.